# Error message I am getting when try to ping

Tags: windows-7

I can't ping to the host network. I am getting this error message:

> destination host unreachable packets:sent =4.received=1.lost=3(75% loss).

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all.

> Destination host unreachable

Some node in your network is sending you that message. Since from that node destination is not reachable.

To find that node you can do

```
tracert "destination host"
```